# Why ComboBox be dropdown result whole app performance to very slow?

Tags: wpf, performance

I have a wpf application.There is a strange thing that as long as i mousedown the ComboBox droparrow becomes all UI response very slow, regardless of whether ComboBox have items.
Annoying the case only appears on some computers.
Look forward to answering.

Comment: we're going to need more information. Can you post the XAML and code behind for the combobox and its item collection. Also what language are you using?

Comment: Can you check it is still the case when you run it outside of a debugging session?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198645/wpf-combobox-performance-problems-by-binding-a-large-collections

Answer (score 3):

I have looked out the tips that you can find on the internet and I just noticed there are no problems.

The following things should be followed carefully, because otherwise the virtualization is gone (taken from MSDN, [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx)):

- Item containers are added directly to the ItemsControl. For example, if an application explicitly adds ListBoxItem objects to a ListBox, the ListBox does not virtualize the ListBoxItem objects.
- Setting CanContentScroll to false.
- Setting IsVirtualizing to false.
- Using item grouping.

The following style works for me without problems.

```
<Style x:Key="SimpleComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<ComboBox Name="cbTest" IsEditable="True" Style="{StaticResource SimpleComboBox}" />
```

After I played around for a while with the style of [Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/), I noticed a small thing. With this style I've had problems when I used `IsEditable = "True"`, the performance goes down!

The following style works for me perfect

```
<Style x:Key="SimpleComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid>
          <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Focusable="false" ClickMode="Press"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <ToggleButton.Template>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="2" Background="#C0C0C0" BorderBrush="#404040" BorderThickness="1" />
                  <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" Margin="1" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#404040" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
                  <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Fill="#404040" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#808080" />
                  </Trigger>
                  <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#E0E0E0" />
                  </Trigger>
                  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAAAAA" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="#888888" />
                  </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
          </ToggleButton>
          <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False"
            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
            Margin="3,3,23,3"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
          <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="3,3,23,3" Focusable="True" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}">
            <TextBox.Template>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
              </ControlTemplate>
            </TextBox.Template>
          </TextBox>
          <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
            <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
              <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#888888"/>
              <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
              </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
          </Popup>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
          </Trigger>
          <!-- remove this trigger, because the virtualization is broken!!!
          <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
          </Trigger>
          -->                
          <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
                   Value="true">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Style.Triggers>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have also removed this trigger.

```
<Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
</Trigger>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you still have the same issue when there's no data in the `ComboBox`, I suspect this is a styling issue.

In the `ComboBox` default style, the only thing that gets affected by mouseover is this `ButtonChrome` control inside the `ToggleButton` which is where you click to expand the `CombBox`.

```
<Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
```

You can first try removing the code

```
RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
```

or replacing it completely with a `Border` (note you will need to remove the `IsChecked` trigger as well)

```
<Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
```

and see if the issue is gone.

I am not 100% sure what's causing it, would be helpful if you can post your xaml code. :)