# WPF Combo box Unresponsive

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, combobox

I am calling data from a WCF service and populating a combo box in my WPF application. As soon as I navigate to the location of the Combo box the page freezes or sometimes I get to open the combo box but then it also freezes?

**WPF**

```
 private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
            {
                await LoadPhase(TSC, cmbtest);

            }

    private async Task LoadPhase (TruckServiceClient TSC, ComboBox combobox)
    {
        List<Phasetems> phasetems = new List<Phasetems>();
        foreach (var item in await TSC.GetphaseAsync())
            phasetems.Add(new Phasetems { Phase = item.Phase });
        combobox.ItemsSource = (phasetems.ToArray());
        combobox.IsEnabled = true;
        combobox.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }

    public class Phasetems
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Phase { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Phase;
        }
    }
```

**WCF**

```
public List<RPhases> Getphase()
        {
            List<RPhases> phases = new List<RPhases>();
            List<RPhases> dbphase;

            using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
                dbphase = db.RPhases.Where(x => x.Id != null).ToList();
            foreach (var a in dbphase)
            {
                var items = new RPhases
                {
                   Id = a.Id,
                   Phase = a.Phase 
                };
                phases.Add(items);
            }
            return phases;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure if it's just hang or there's an exception hidden in the background ?
you need to call CheckAccess/BeginInvoke whenever you want to update your control from a background thread (i.e. combobox)

Comment: The default behaviour of `await` is going back on the thread which called the async method. So he doesn´t need to call CheckAccess or so. @RGdent: Could there be anything else blocking the ui thread? Another Loaded-handler or so?

Comment: No there isn't any other loaders at all @christoph it is not just the combo box that freezes but the program as well.

Comment: Is it a large list?  You may need virtualization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198645/wpf-combobox-performance-problems-by-binding-a-large-collections

Comment: Did you try it without the service call? Just to make sure nothing else is blocking?

Comment: I did find another Loader and the problem was there.. @christoph `private async void cmbtest_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
            {
                await LoadClient(TSC, cmbtest);
            }
        }`

Comment: I called the same combo box in my load client the the selection changed.. @christoph thanks you had the right idea

Comment: @RGdent Great, that you could solve the problem. I posted the last comment as answer to have the steps that helped you out better visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is correct and doesn´t create that ui blocking behaviour (as far as I can see).

Make sure nothing else is blocking the ui thread. Try it without the service call to see whether it still blocks it.

You can use Visual Studio break feature to step into running code and find out where it is.