# Adding hundreds of entries into a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, list, dictionary, combobox

I have over 300 entries that I want to add to a combobox from a dictionary in my WPF application.

```
public Dictionary<int, string> NameList()
{
        Dictionary<int, string> names = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 1, "John Johnson" }
        }
}
```

That dictionary goes all the way to 382 (if there's a better alternative to using a dictionary please let me know and why :))

And in my MainWindow constructor I have a void method `LoadNames()` which contains:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            NameComboBox.ItemsSource = NameList().Values;
        });
```

However, when opening the MainWindow there is a noticeable lag/delay for the application to start up, and also a delay when opening the combobox for the first time.

Is there a better way to implement this, possibly asynchronously? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have test virtualization panel
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198645/wpf-combobox-performance-problems-by-binding-a-large-collections

Comment: @G.Sofien this article worked wonders, thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found that the best way of implementing a solution to this scenario is to have your combobox implement a itempaneltemplate with a virtualizingstackpanel. In addition use a backgroundworker process to load the combobox. I have had implemented this with comboboxes that contained 1000's of items.